# Learning how to mix Telerik AJAX controls with MVC -- Seeing garbage characters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

I am attempting to find a place to start debugging this issue at.
I do not experience this issue if I create a new, MVC2 project, but I am trying to integrate into our companies existing MVC solution.

I am adding a ScriptManager to the MasterPage. Something like this:

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableTheming="True" EnablePageMethods="True">
</telerik:RadScriptManager>
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4Pf3.jpg) is what I see when I try and run.

I'm extremely new to MVC and unsure of where/how to start debugging this. I have a hunch it has something to do with either the Global ASAX or Web Config file, but without any more information I'm not sure where to begin poking around.

Has anyone seen this before?

partial-answer: it seems that moving the script manager inside of the closing  tag resolved this issue, but the second I tried to add a control to my View I am back to looking at garbage. Plus, it doesn't match what I had to do in the default app. Wondering why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some asp.net controls simply won't work in MVC because they rely on features that MVC doesn't support, such as viewstate.  I'm not sure if the Telerik ajax controls are in this boat or not, but you can't assume any control will work.  Generally, the more complex the control, the less likely it will work.

I notice that you have it working in a default project, but perhaps that project has no real data or doesn't use the same features that your production app uses.

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/mvc-getting-started.html

Telerik controls, for the most part, are supported. I am doing the very very very most basic thing, not even adding an actual control with content -- just the script manager. This is 100% a supported control.

I am in agreement with you that the production app is introducing conflicting data, but I am curious if its just like... a route redirection, or something. I don't know what 'things' could be conflicting in the MVC environment.

Comment: @Sean Anderson - Not sure if PageMethods or Theming are supported in MVC, you could try making those false. Also, are you registering the HTTP Handler?

Comment: Yes, the HTTP Handler is registered. I've copied the web.config over from our production app and the Rad AJAX control is still showing up, it is (probably) something outside of this web.config file.

Comment: @Sean Anderson - I'm curious as to why you have an Html.EndForm() and `</form>`

Comment: I do not know. I have inherited this code and Html.EndForm() is completely new to me.

Comment: @Mystere Man You, my friend, are on to something! I was able to reproduce certain parts of my error. This is enough. Thank you for your sharp eyes.

Comment: So, removing the <form> and </form> tags fixes the issue with script manager in the Master page, but I am encountering the same issue as before when trying to have a control on my Home/Index view. I wonder what other things I could look for that would be attributable to this.

Comment: @Mystere Man, There is a way to get Ajax controls to work in MVC by doing some special ViewState handling. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424531/telerik-asp-net-ajax-radgrid-in-mvc-and-viewstate